# Having trouble creating a class based implementation of OpenCV's mouseCallback function

Tags: c++, class, opencv, callback, mouse

As the title suggest, I'm having some trouble implementing OpenCV's mouseCallback function in a class based C++ structure. Allow me to explain. I have defined a class called BriskMatching in which I have created a member function named mouseCallback with the correct parameters that OpenCV requires (please see the code snippet below).

```
**Briskmatching.h**

class BriskMatching
{
public:
    BriskMatching();
    ~BriskMatching();

public:
    void mouseCallback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param);
};
```

This is all fine, however my problem arises when I try to set this function as the designated mouse callback function through OpenCV's `cv::setMouseCallback` function.

In my main function, I create an instance of the BriskMatching class called briskMatcher then when it comes time to set the mouse callback I attempt to do it like so...

```
cv::setMouseCallback("Matches", BriskMatching::mouseCallback, &matchesImg);
```

Unfortunately, this throws an error.

```
Error   3   error C3867: 'BriskMatching::mouseCallback': function call missing argument list; use '&BriskMatching::mouseCallback' to create a pointer to member c:\users\mobilef\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opencv_objtracking\opencv_briskmatching\main.cpp 54  1   OpenCV_BriskMatching
```

I could get rid of this error by declaring the mouseCallback function as `static` in `BriskMatching.h` but then I get a whole whack of other errors since I refer to many non-static member variables in the mouseCallback function.

So my question to you guys is this. How should I modify my code to be able to properly pass my mouseCallback function declared within the BriskMatching class to the `cv::setMouseCallback` function?

Thanks for all your help in advanced!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since a member function takes a `this` pointer, you will need a static wrapper function. Typically, you use the `param` parameter to be the address of the object that the member function belongs to, so you end up with something like this:

```
...
static void mouseCallback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param);

void doMouseCallback(int event, int x, int y, int flags);
```

And then inside the `mouseCallback`:

```
void BriskMatching::mouseCallback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    BriskMatching *self = static_cast<BriskMatching*>(param);
    self->doMouseCallback(event, x, y, flags);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It works great, but I don't completely understand the logic behind it or how it works. I've been coding in C++ for a few years now, but I've always avoided type casts and so its always been a bit of grey area to me. I'm going to go read up on them now, and try to understand how this all works.

Answer (score 0):

I was using this method too, however I realized that the static helper class was quite rigid and type and method bound.

Just for further reference I've defined a templated free function that looks like:

```
template<typename TClass, void (TClass::*MouseClickType)(int, int, int, int)>
void FreeOnMouseCallback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* ptr)
{
    auto* mcPtr = static_cast<TClass*>(ptr);
    if(mcPtr != NULL)
    {
      (mcPtr->*MouseClickType)(event, x, y, flags);
    }
}
```

And I can now call arbitrary functions (matching the signature, but not the name) inside classes with

```
 cv::setMouseCallback( WindowName, FreeOnMouseCallback<Calibrator, &Calibrator::OnMouseCallback>, this );
```

It might be extended if the void* ptr is also required, but I've omitted it here.