# how to set multiple callback function for single opencv window

Tags: c++, opencv, window

Say we have two callback functions,

```
void foo1(int event,int x,int y,int flag,void* param);
void foo2(int event,int x,int y,int flag,void* param);
```

and we have a window,

```
std::string winName = "srcImage";
cv::namedWindow(winName);
```

now say we set foo1 as the callback function for this window,

```
cv::setMouseCallback(winName ,foo1);
//do some stuff
```

now if we do this,

```
cv::setMouseCallback(winName ,foo2);
```

foo2 is the only callback function for this window.

But if we want to keep both functions and for that matter, say, we want to set arbitrary number of functions as callback functions, what we have to do ? 
And I want to keep that solution in a library.

Comment: The easiest option is to write a function that calls all of the other functions in turn. If you set that as the callback, then all of the other functions will be called as desired.

Comment: If you want a general solution, you could write a class-based mouse callback that allows you to register additional functions to call (i.e. the class has something like an `add_listener` member function). This might be helpful in that regard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589841/having-trouble-creating-a-class-based-implementation-of-opencvs-mousecallback-f